# How can I extract a feature from a genbank file by label?

Tags: feature-extraction, biopython, genbank

I'm trying to parse a genbank file to find a specific feature.  I can pull it out if I know the feature type (e.g. repeat_region) - eg if I'm looking for this feature:

```
 repeat_region   5623..5756
                 /label=5' ITR
                 /note="5' ITR"
```

I know that I can find it using:

```
for feature in reference.features:
if feature.type == "repeat_region":
    print(feature.location)
```

But I don't trust that it will always be a repeat_region.  Instead, I'd like to look for it by label (5' ITR).  I can seem to find a way to parse that from the feature object.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you first start by isolating cases your current method fails to work properly. Perhaps do some full document searches for the terms "5' ITR" and "5' Inverted Terminal Repeat". You'll likely be able to find instances where your target terms are reported inconsistently, complicating the parsing process. Expand your function when/if you've determined it's necessary to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to try using the ElementTree library; it will parse the genbank xml file into a dictionary and then you should be able to access the /label tag as a key.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).